# How to return an index of each given answer as a result in multiselect prompt in Enquirer?

Tags: node.js, prompt, multi-select, inquirerjs

I'm *using* [Enquirer](https://github.com/enquirer/enquirer), **not** [Inquirer](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js), but there is no tag for `Enquirer` and I don't have 1500 reputation to create one, so I'm using `Inquirerjs` instead.

Code of example prompt, where I tried to use object choices (got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65415773/15941124)), but it does not contain value with zero index. That's unproductive solution anyway. Also I remember that somehow, when I was trying to get only values from pair of key:value from custom map, about which says [official documentation](https://github.com/enquirer/enquirer#multiselect-prompt:%7E:text=Optionally%2C%20pass%20a%20result%20function%20and%20use%20the%20.map%20method%20to%20return%20an%20object%20of%20key%2Dvalue%20pairs%20of%20the%20selected%20names%20and%20values%3A%20example) and its [given example](https://github.com/enquirer/enquirer/blob/36785f3399a41cd61e9d28d1eb9c2fcd73d69b4c/examples/multiselect/option-result.js#L28), I got the indexes of answers, but as I sat here brainstorming for an hour - sadly, I cannot remeber how I did it. So, how do you do it, what it says in the title?

Tried:

```js
enquirer.prompt({
    type: 'multiselect',
    name: 'choice',
    choices: [
        {name: `dynamiclyGeneratedName`, value: `dynamicID`},
        {name: `dynamiclyGeneratedName`, value: `dynamicID`},
        ...
    ],
    result (result) {
        return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(this.choices).filter(([key, value]) => value.enabled));
    },
})
.then(async (result) => {
    console.log(result);
})
.catch(console.error);
```

From official documentation:

```js
  result(names) {
   return this.map(names);
  }
```

Expected result:

```js
{
    choice: [0, 6, 9]
}
```